# JPA reading/referencing annotations programmatically

Tags: jpa

I am new to JPA. The requirement is that I need to read the metadata from the bean. for example

```
public class Applicant {

    @Id
    @Column(name="ApplicationId")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name="ApplicantName")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="DateOfBirth")
    private String dateOfBirth;
    @Column(name="CellNo")
    private int contactNo;
}
```

and I want to read all the column names programmatically.

Comment: I'm sure that's not your real requirement. What do you really want to achieve? What have you tried?

Comment: Yes. I also think that this is just a escape solution. The problem is that this is a very big table(say having 50 columns) and the user wants to see 5 columns plus it should be also configurable. Eg: One user can configure to see 5 columns today and 10 columns tomorrow. So we are maintaining a separate table to store the column names , a user want to see. Everything was fine until we were using the traditional JDBC but now the project needs to be upgraded to Spring with Hibernate using JPA. So please provide me any help to achieve this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reflection to access the annotations.

Most JPA providers also provide APIs to access their meta-data.
For EclipseLink you can unwrap an EntityManager to a Session and access the ClassDescriptor through getDescriptor().  The ClassDescriptor contains all of the meta-data for a class, including the columns (fields).

Comment: I am using hibernate to implement JPA. Is the process for reading the metadata is same for EclipseLink and hibernate?